# AsyncIO and concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, multithreading, coroutine

I'm building a web scraping API, and most of my scraping is done with AsyncIO coroutines, like this:

```
async def parse_event(self):
   do scraping

# call the func
asyncio.run(b.parse_event())
```

This works perfectly fine, but as I'm **scraping** multiple websites at the same time, I was using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` at first to **scrape** with multiple threads.
But since I've implemented the coroutine logic, I cannot now use the `asyncio.run` method in my thread directly.

Before (without coroutine):

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
     w1_future = executor.submit(self.w1.parse_event)
     w2_future = executor.submit(self.w2.parse_event)
     w3_future = executor.submit(self.w3.parse_event)
```

After, I would have expected something like below

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
     w1_future = executor.submit(asyncio.run(self.w1.parse_event))
     w2_future = executor.submit(asyncio.run(self.w2.parse_event))
     w3_future = executor.submit(asyncio.run(self.w3.parse_event))
```

Unfortunately it is not working.

Comment: Due to GIL it is unlikely that multiple threads will actually result in a performance gain compared to async.

Comment: ``asyncio`` is already a way to use a single CPU concurrently, just as ``threading`` is a way to use a single CPU concurrently. You gain nothing by throwing both at the same task.

Comment: If you really want to, it should be ``executor.submit(asyncio.run, self.w1.parse_event)`` instead.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi is `asyncio.run` guaranteed to be thread safe? Since it is not mentioned in 
the docs, I would assume it is not, and so this is not safe.

Comment: I've reopened the question. Passing `asyncio.run` with parameters to the executor is not safe.

Comment: @freakish ``asyncio.run`` doesn't do any concurrency by itself, so it's about as thread safe as ``+``. The operands are what makes the operation thread safe or not.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi `executor.submit(asyncio.run, self.w1.parse_event)` will run `asyncio.run` in seperate threads. So I'm asking you: is `asyncio.run` thread safe?

Comment: @freakish This is not speculation, this is working with ``asyncio`` for ages. The docs *do not* say that ``asyncio.run`` is thread-safe, just as the docs do not talk about thread safety for most things.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes, everything that is not **explicitly** stated as thread safe should be assumed to be not thread safe. Most things in Python are not thread safe. That's precisely why methods like `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe` exist.

Comment: @freakish ``asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`` is for submitting a coroutine to an event loop *across* threads. That's something completely different than running event loops that do not interact.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi you've missed the point: `run_coroutine_threadsafe` is thread safe because it is explicitly stated to be. Thread safety of `parse_event` is for the OP to take care of. Again: there is no indication that `asyncio.run` is thread safe and so no reason to believe it is. Even if it is thread safe now, it may not be tomorrow. The Python docs don't guarantee it is. Ergo the code you've propsed is simply not guaranteed to be thread safe. That's all there is to it, no point in discussing this anymore.

Comment: I've removed my answer. After further analysis I don't think this can be done in a thread safe way, unless the standard guarantees that loops themselves don't share any state and can be used independently from threads. Which I couldn't find. Still, even if they were threadsafe it is unlikely that the executor will result in a performance gain.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi What if are dealing with I/O so it is not CPU bound like a hard drive or camera. Then splitting something off to a separate thread makes sense right?

Comment: @TheCodeNovice In this case *No*, since that is what asyncio already does. Both asyncio and threading are for I/O bound tasks - there is little point using both unless it's for compatibility with existing code.

Answer (score 14):

Both `asyncio` and threading are a means to use a single core for concurrent operations. However, this works via different mechanisms: `asyncio` uses the *cooperative* concurrency of `async`/`await` whereas threading uses the *preemptive* concurrency of the [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock).
Mixing the two does not speed up execution since both still use the same single core; instead, overhead of both mechanisms will slow down the program and the interaction of the mechanisms complicates writing correct code.

To achieve concurrency between multiple tasks, submit them all to a single `asyncio` event loop. The equivalent to `executor.submit` is [`asyncio.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task); multiple tasks can be submitted at once using [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather). Note that both are called *inside* the loop as opposed to *outside* the executor.

```py
async def parse_all():
    return await asyncio.gather(
        # all the parsing tasks that should run concurrently
        self.w1.parse_event,
        self.w2.parse_event,
        self.w3.parse_event,
    )

asyncio.run(parse_all())
```

---

If you absolutely do want to use separate, threaded event loops for each parse, you must [use `executor.submit(func, *args)` instead of `executor.submit(func(args))`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.submit).

```py
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
     w1_future = executor.submit(asyncio.run, self.w1.parse_event())
     w2_future = executor.submit(asyncio.run, self.w2.parse_event())
     w3_future = executor.submit(asyncio.run, self.w3.parse_event())
```

Note that [mixing `asyncio` and threading adds complexity and constraints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#asyncio-multithreading). You might want to use [debug mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#debug-mode) to detect some thread and context safety issues. However, thread and context safety constraints/guarantees are often not documented; manually test or inspect the operations for safety if needed.